# Unable to create temporary GeoDatasets in g_g_g folders

Tags: arcgis-10.0, .net, vb.net, error-010240

I am converting a VBA macro that was written for ArcGIS 9.3 to a VB.NET project using the ArcGIS 10.0 .NET SDK. I am getting the following error whenever the code tries to create a temporary IGeoDataset in a "g_g_g" folder:

"(esriDataSourcesRaster.GdalDriver) Failed to copy raster dataset ERROR 010240: Could not save raster dataset to E:\temp\g_g_g2 with output format GRID." (with the g_g_g2 incrementing by 1 with each failed attempt)

It is able to create the "g_g_g" folder as well as create two files: dbldbnd.adf and hdr.adf before it fails. When it creates a "raster" folder, it creates these files as well as 5 other .adf files and a log file.

It creates a temporary IGeoDataset in a "raster" folder just fine. I have tried a number of things to get past this error without any luck.

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

I have never used ArcGIS before, so if there is some important detail I have failed to add, please let me know.

Comment: So if you don't use the underscores it works just fine?

Comment: I'm not specifying the format of the temporary folders, they are being generated by Arc. I don't know why it creates a "g_g_g" folder vs a "raster" folder, I just noticed that it only bombs when it tries to create the "g_g_g" folder.

Comment: I changed my environment setting within the contour tool. I changed the worspace to the database I am currently using; instead of the ArcGIS default gdb. I am using version 10.0 sp 5. I was running the tool in ArcMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by installing Service Pack 3 for ArcGIS 10.0 and for the .NET SDK found at http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=66&MetaID=1807.
There were no Service Packs installed previously.